# Iterate through list of lists and remove unwanted strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having a play about and I've scraped a ingredient list from a website.
I now have a list of lists.

```
ingrediant_list = []

for ingrediant in soup.select('.wprm-recipe-ingredient'):
    ingrediant_list.append(ingrediant.text)

full_list = []

for item in ingrediant_list:
    full_list.append(item.split())
```

This is my code that generates the list of lists. First I get the ingredients from the website and throw them into `ingrediants_list`; then I split each string into a separate list generating a list of lists under `full_list`

My list is as follows:

> [['400', 'g', '5%', 'Fat', 'Minced', 'Beef'], ['1', 'large', 'Onion',
> 'finely', 'chopped'], ['3', 'cloves', 'Garlic', 'finely', 'grated'],
> ['5', 'Mushrooms', 'sliced'], ['1', 'large', 'Carrot', 'finely',
> 'chopped'], ['1', 'stick', 'Celery', 'finely', 'chopped'], ['1',
> 'Red', 'Pepper', 'finely', 'chopped'], ['2', 'tins', 'Chopped',
> 'Tomatoes'], ['1', 'tbsp', 'Tomato', 'Puree'], ['1', 'tbsp', 'Mixed',
> 'Italian', 'Herbs'], ['1', 'tbsp', 'Balsamic', 'Vinegar'], ['1',
> 'Red', 'Wine', 'Stock', 'Pot'], ['250', 'ml', 'Beef', 'Stock', 'make',
> 'using', '1-2', 'beef', 'stock', 'cubes'], ['dash', "Henderson's",
> 'Relish/Worcestershire', 'Sauce'], ['Low', 'Calorie', 'Cooking',
> 'Spray'], ['200', 'g', 'Dried', 'Pasta', 'use', 'whichever', 'shape',
> 'you', 'prefer'], ['80', 'g', 'Reduced', 'Fat', 'Cheddar', 'Cheese']]

How can I iterate through this list of lists removing strings like 'finely', 'chopped' and 'grated', replace the 'tbsp' with 'grams', and then create another list similar to 'ingrediants_list' with none of stuff I didn't want?

Comment: `[['grams' if i == 'tbsp' else i for i in l if i.lower() not in {'finely', 'chopped', 'grated'}] for l in full_list]`

Comment: A tablespoon is usually more than a gram.

Comment: "removing strings like 'finely', 'chopped' and 'grated', replace the 'tbsp' with 'grams', and then create another list similar to 'ingrediants_list' with none of stuff I didn't want?" This isn't precise enough of a description to write code. You need to be able to say, for example, what the rule is that tells you whether a string is "like" 'finely', 'chopped' or 'grated', or not.

Comment: But in any case, first try to write a function that handles a single ingredient, and then you can apply that to the list by iterating.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Works great, Thank you for that. are you able to explain what exactly is going on so i can understand it a bit better?

Comment: @BILLYBOB, I've posted extended answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it's not necessary to split string to replace unnecessary words, you can use `str.replace()`:

```py
full_list = []
replace_rules = {
    'finely': '',
    'chopped': '',
    'grated': '',
    'tbsp': 'grams'
}
for s in ingrediant_list:
    for old, new in replace_rules.items():
        s = s.replace(old, new)
    full_list.append(s.rstrip())  # .rstrip() removes trailing spaces if exist
```

Code above works but it will replace words only in lower case. We can use *regular expressions* to solve it:

```py
import re

full_list = []
replace_rules = {
    r'\s*(finely|chopped|grated)': '',
    r'(\s*)tbsp': r'\1grams'
}
for s in ingrediant_list:
    for old, new in replace_rules.items():
        s = re.sub(old, new, s, re.IGNORECASE)
    full_list.append(s)
```

If, for some reasons, you need to split sentences, you can just use nested loop:

```py
replace_rules = {
    'finely': '',
    'chopped': '',
    'grated': '',
    'tbsp': 'grams'
}
result_list = []
for l in full_list:
    temp_list = []
    for w in l:
        if w.lower() in replace_rules:
            if replace_rules[w.lower()]:
                temp_list.append(replace_rules[w.lower()])
        else:
            temp_list.append(w)
    result_list.append(temp_list)
```

Or you can do the same using list comprehension:

```
filter_list = {'finely', 'chopped', 'grated'}  # words to ignore
replace_rules = {'tbsp': 'grams'}              # words to replace
result_list = [[replace_rules.get(w.lower(), w) for w in l if w.lower() not in filter_list] for l in full_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
newlist  = [i for i in oldlist if unwanted_string not in i]
```

I'll expand with an example

```
item_list = ["BigCar", "SmallCar", "BigHouse", "SmallHouse"]
unwanted_string = "Big"
[i for i in item_list if not unwanted_string in i]
```

Result:

```
['SmallCar', 'SmallHouse']
```

Comment: Also your code won't remove `"big"` or `"BiG"`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, i have tried this code but it removes the entire sentence with whatever `unwanted_string` is equal too. So in my instance it removes complete ingredients and I don't want that